# Textarea input length check in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, textarea

I'd like to create an SMS gateway which alerts the user each time when 160 chars are written (or pasted). I need to store a variable n containing number of message parts of 160 chars. The code will be like this, just the n needs to be stored globally. Is there any better way than e. g. storing it into a hidden form field?
Note: an assumption that less than 160 chars will be pasted at once is safe in this particular case.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var n=1;   
  var t=document.getElementById('msg');
  t.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var l=t.value.length;
    if(l>n*160){
      n++;
      alert('Message will be split into '+n+' parts');   
    }
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with n after you've calculated it. Do you want to submit it along with the textarea's contents?

Comment: Well, looks like it's actually a working solution, I probably overlooked something before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it depends on what you want to do with `n` ultimately.

If you just want it to show the user a message, you can update the DOM once you've calculated this value.

Your current example doesn't allow the user to delete text after they've typed/pasted it in. A better example would be stateless, i.e. don't compare `n` to itself, as in my example below:

```js
var t = document.getElementById('msg');
var splitSize = 10;
var n = 1;
t.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var nextN = 1;
  
  if (t.value.length > 0) {
    nextN = Math.ceil(t.value.length / splitSize);
  }
  
  if (n !== nextN) {
    n = nextN;
    var label = document.getElementById('label');

    if (n === 1) {
      label.innerHTML = '';
    } else {
      label.innerHTML = 'The message will be split into ' + n + ' parts';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="label"></p>
<textarea id="msg"></textarea>
```